# How to tunnel/proxy/forward traffic from remote VSCode instance

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy, portforwarding, vscode-remote

Currently I am accessing my VS code instance through [it's remote feature](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack). Sometimes it's SSH, sometimes K8s pod, sometimes remote Docker instance.

After I am able to attach VSCode to that remote instance, I can connect to some resources behind that instance ( Database, internal services... ). The configuration is like this

MyLocalPC -------------------------> RemoteVSServer -------------------------> Database

I can see that in VSCode there is a feature where ports on the [RemoveVSServer] can be forwarded to [MyLocalPC]

[image]

Here I can access RemoveVSServer:3000 from MyLocalPC:3000

My question is that is there any feature where I can access [Database]:9999 from [MyLocalPC]. By VSCode default or a plugin/extension/small application

Answer (score 0):

Finally I installed HAProxy on the instance that run VSCode Server

The HAProxy map remote port 9999 to VSCode Server's port 9999

From there I can do one more port-forward from VSCode Server's port 9999 to my local PC's port 9999

A simple config for HA Proxy can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/cmer/e58e90dbf820a850ff4f136f85697be0)